# vb.net loop running next too fast

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in my vb application:

```
    For Each fi In aryFi
        If System.IO.File.Exists(fi.FullName) = True Then
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + "File: " + fi.Name + vbCrLf
            TextBox2.Refresh()

            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + "Printing File" + vbCrLf
            TextBox2.Refresh()
            ' Create object, passing in text
            Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
            psi.UseShellExecute = True
            psi.Verb = "print"
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            psi.FileName = fi.FullName

            Dim p = Process.Start(psi)

            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + "Moving File" + vbCrLf
            TextBox2.Refresh()
            System.IO.File.Move(My.Settings.FolderPath + "\" + fi.Name, My.Settings.FolderPath + "\COMPLETED\" + fi.Name)
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "------------------------------------------------------------" + vbCrLf
            TextBox2.Refresh()

            p.WaitForExit()

        End If
    Next
```

It loops through a directory of files and prints each file individually.

Once it has printed the file, it moves it into another directory so its not processed again.

It seems that, it is running the next loop before the file has been moved so its trying to print the same file over and over again

how can i stop this from happening

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're doing here, but try using `p.WaitForExit()` instead of `If p.HasExited() Then`

Comment: where should i put that? just before the End If that checks if the file exists

Comment: No - remove your `End If` and replace the `If p.HasExited() Then` statement with it.  What you're doing is starting a process then immediately saying "has it exited yet"? and the answer is almost certainly always going to be "no", and your code will skip the if block and carry on.  Whereas `p.WaitForExit()` will pause your code while the process does whatever it needs to.

Comment: check my update - is that corerct or should it be at the top of the loop rather than the bottom?

Comment: No - It should be immediately after `Process.Start(psi)`, replacing the `If` statement I mentioned.  I have no idea if it will fix your problem or not - it's just your existing code looked like it was attempting to wait for the process to exit, when actually it probably never would have.

Comment: Also - please don't edit your question with new code unless it's exhibiting the exact same behaviour you're describing alongside it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just quickly read all of the files into a list in memory, and then process that entire list once?